# Python XGBoost GPU Error: Check failed: gpu_predictor_

Tags: python, gpu, fedora, xgboost

I'm running the following code

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_covtype
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import time

# Fetch dataset using sklearn
cov = fetch_covtype()
X = cov.data
y = cov.target

# Create 0.75/0.25 train/test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, train_size=0.75,
                                                    random_state=42)

# Specify sufficient boosting iterations to reach a minimum
num_round = 3000

# Leave most parameters as default
param = {'objective': 'multi:softmax', # Specify multiclass classification
         'num_class': 8, # Number of possible output classes
         'tree_method': 'gpu_hist' # Use GPU accelerated algorithm
         }

# Convert input data from numpy to XGBoost format
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)

gpu_res = {} # Store accuracy result
tmp = time.time()
# Train model
xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, evals=[(dtest, 'test')], evals_result=gpu_res)
print("GPU Training Time: %s seconds" % (str(time.time() - tmp)))

# Repeat for CPU algorithm
tmp = time.time()
param['tree_method'] = 'hist'
cpu_res = {}
xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, evals=[(dtest, 'test')], evals_result=cpu_res)
print("CPU Training Time: %s seconds" % (str(time.time() - tmp)))
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [bt] (0)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0xa0c64)
> [0x7f6c9bba4c64]   [bt] (1)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x168b73)
> [0x7f6c9bc6cb73]   [bt] (2)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x168e82)
> [0x7f6c9bc6ce82]   [bt] (3)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x1994f7)
> [0x7f6c9bc9d4f7]   [bt] (4)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(XGBoosterUpdateOneIter+0x59)
> [0x7f6c9bb94d39]   [bt] (5)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.7(+0x69dd)
> [0x7f6cee5279dd]   [bt] (6)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.7(+0x6067)
> [0x7f6cee527067]   [bt] (7)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1097a)
> [0x7f6cee53d97a]   [bt] (8)
> /home/darfeder/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x110db)
> [0x7f6cee53e0db]

I suspect that it's caused by incompatibility between my current python version: 3.8.3

> (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59)  [GCC 7.3.0]

and the cuda installation:

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019 Cuda compilation
> tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uninstall the nvidia drivers and reinstall the cuda toolkit drivers